# How to update a specific field in SQLite with key id?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to update the field isActive in my SQLite database to specific user using his id, He's active if the field equals to 1, and not active field equals 0.  I want to update from 1(Active) to 0(not active). cv = ContentValue, db = SQLiteDatabase, hlp = HelperDB.

```
cv.put(Student.isActive, 0);
db = hlp.getWritableDatabase();
db.update(TABLE_STUDENTS, cv, key, null);
db.close();
```

Comment: You've posted a desire and uncommented code but you will also want to 1) tell us what problems you're having with the code, and 2) ask a more specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution would be....

```
public void isActive(int id, boolean isActive) 
{
    int is_active = (isActive) ? 1 : 0;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();    
    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(IS_ACTIVE, is_active);

        // The columns for the WHERE clause
        String selection = (ID+ " = ?");

        // The values for the WHERE clause
        String[] selectionArgs = {id};

        db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, selection, selectionArgs);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```